# Can't validate my form in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-form

So I create a form and I want to use it in my project. I use **Zend Framework 2** and **Doctrine Orm**. The problem occurs when I submit the form: I had nothing, that means the form wasn't submitted. For more details I will write my code. So if someone has any solution I will be very appreciative.

**This is my entity :**

```
class Article implements InputFilterAwareInterface
{   
    protected $inputFilter;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="publication", type="boolean")
     */
    protected  $publication;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->date = new \Datetime();
}

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $title;

   // ....

   /**
    * Populate from an array.
    *
    * @param array $data
    */
    // here maybe the data can't pass from my form to the entity !!
   public function populate($data = array())
   {
        $this->content = $data['content'];
        $this->title = $data['title'];
        $this->date = $data['date'];
        $this->publication = $data['publication'];
        $this->image = $data['image'];
   }

   public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter)
   {
       throw new \Exception("Not used");
   }

   public function getInputFilter()
   {
       if (!$this->inputFilter) {
          $inputFilter = new InputFilter();

          $factory = new InputFactory();

          $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
              'name'     => 'content',
              'required' => true,
              'filters'  => array(
                  array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                  array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
              ),
              'validators' => array(
                  array(
                      'name'    => 'StringLength',
                      'options' => array(
                          'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                          'min'      => 60,
                      ),
                  ),
              ),
          )));

          // ....
    }
}
```

**Then my Action:**

```
$form = new ArticleForm();
$form->get('submit')->setAttribute('label', 'Add');
$request = $this->getRequest();

if ($this->zfcUserAuthentication()->hasIdentity()) {
    if ($request->isPost()) 
    {
        $article = new Article();
        $form->setInputFilter($article->getInputFilter());
        $form->setData($request->getPost());
        if ($form->isValid()) { 
            $article->populate($form->getData());// here i think i have a problem
            $this->getObjectManager()->flush();
            $newId = $article->getId();

            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('blog');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of : `$article->populate($form->getData());`

try: `$article->populate($request->getPost()->toArray());//bad idea`

or : `$article->populate($form->getData()->toArray());//good idea`

up:
`$form->getData()` will return entity so you must implement `toArray()` function;

```
public function toArray()
{
  return array(
    'title' => $this->title,
    //...
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Notuser, still not working i think the problem in the populate function

Comment: var_dump on $form->getData()->toArray() and check if this array have same keys as in populate

Comment: @Mohammadov sorry i forgot that you must to add function toArray() to your entity